# Maximum of each pair of index of the array

Tags: java, arrays, list, performance, arraylist

I need to create an array, compare each pair of this array, and then find and print the largest element of each pair. I have created an array like below, but it's printing me only the two largest of the whole array!

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {1, -5, 2, 6, 10, 7};

        int a = arr[0];
        int b = arr[1];

        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (a > b || b > a) {
                    a = arr[i];
                    b = arr[j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

In the example below, I have 3 pairs (6 elements) and I want to get maximum of each pair as an example:

- **Input:** {1, -5, 2, 6, 10, 7}
- **Output:** 1, 6, 10

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program does not print the two largest numbers. It prints the two last numbers of the array. If you add a 200 in the mid of the array, it will still print 10 and 7.

Also, the `System.out.println()`-lines are outside any loop, so they will run only once.

If you want to get the higher number out of the first and second, the third and fourth, fifth and sixth element and so on (due to the expected output, I assume this is what you want to get), then the for-loop will fail like this. On each run of the loop, it will check if a > b or b > a. If that's the case, a gets the value of arr[i] and b the value of arr[j]. On the last run, i will be the second last value and j the last value of the array, so you will always get the last two elements. Unless you compare two times the same value in the array, then a and b will get the same value and nothing will change anymore from there.

If you want to compare the pairs like I described, then maybe you should instead try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2)
{
    if(!(i == arr.length-1)) // in case there is no i+1 index anymore
    {
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        else if(arr[i+1]>arr[i])
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great respond. It is awesome!

I knew that code was wrong, but I wanted to mention the whole structure.